# Is there a possibility of a question getting reviewed more than once?

Tags: discussion, review

With the new review system. Is there a possibility of a question reappearing for review even after somebody reviews it?

If yes, why does it happen?

Question/Answers can be improved by the review process but how long the Q&A will remain on the review system?

Comment: Which review queue are you referring to?  low quality answers, suggested edits, first posts, close votes?

Comment: Previously, posts had to be reviewed by two people before they disappeared from the queue. I assume the same rule still applies.

Comment: @Servy Yes. All that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- low quality posts: 5 votes to delete or looks good (at most) will remove it from the queue.  If the question is deleted by a diamond mod or enough 20k users it will also be removed (whether done from inside or outside of the queue).
- suggested edits: 2 votes to approve/deny on SO (1 from a diamond), or 1 vote on all other sites, will make that action take place
- close votes: 5 votes to close will close it (or 1 from a diamond), 5 to not close will remove from the queue
- first posts: 1 person with action taken *inside of the queue* will result in it being removed. (Not verified for sure; I just went to the history an found none with more than one action taken in the past 50 or so, and the posts in the queue was ticking down as I watched it.)